# Odd school assignment, about displaying emojis in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I've had the pleasure to get the assignment of posting emojis in Powershell, the only problem is they have to be on the same line, and there are three. This is, my first assignment, and we have no prior teaching in this subject so after googling and searching YouTube, my best shot was this below, however, it came with some error saying something about either too high value, or too low value.

Full error text: Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument (s): "The value was either too large or too small to a UInt32. "
At C: \ Users \ EG \ Downloads \ Herningsholm \ Powershell H1 \ Hardware Information.ps1: 3 char: 5
$ UnicodeInt = [System.Convert] :: toInt32 ($ StrippedUnicode, 16)
CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId: OverflowException

```
$FullUnicode = ('U+1F60E') + ('U+1F436') + ('U+1F642')
$StrippedUnicode = $FullUnicode -replace 'U\+',''
$UnicodeInt = [System.Convert]::toInt32($StrippedUnicode,16)
[System.Char]::ConvertFromUtf32($UnicodeInt)
```

Comment: please add your full erorr text to your Question.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i ran that code and got the following error "Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32."". I think he is referring to the same error.

Comment: i repeat ... **_please add your full error text to your Question._**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:
Full emoji list > [here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

```
# saves unicode for each emoji https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html
$FullUnicode0 = 'U+1F606'
$FullUnicode1 = 'U+1F605'
$FullUnicode2 = 'U+1F605'

# removes the U+ bit
$StrippedUnicode0 = $FullUnicode0 -replace 'U\+',''
$StrippedUnicode1 = $FullUnicode1 -replace 'U\+',''
$StrippedUnicode2 = $FullUnicode2 -replace 'U\+',''

# Converts the value of the specified object to a 32-bit signed integer
$UnicodeInt0 = [System.Convert]::toInt32($StrippedUnicode0,16)
$UnicodeInt1 = [System.Convert]::toInt32($StrippedUnicode1,16)
$UnicodeInt2 = [System.Convert]::toInt32($StrippedUnicode2,16)

# Converts the specified Unicode code point into a UTF-16 encoded string so that you have an emoji
$Emoji0 = [System.Char]::ConvertFromUtf32($UnicodeInt0)
$Emoji1 = [System.Char]::ConvertFromUtf32($UnicodeInt1)
$Emoji2 = [System.Char]::ConvertFromUtf32($UnicodeInt2)

write-host "$($Emoji0), $($Emoji1), $($Emoji2)"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this was absolutely helpful! And this actually made me understand better what is supposed to happen, really appreciated. :)

Comment: Glad this helped you out, and resolved the issue. You could mark the answer as answered if it helped you.

Comment: I've never used this site before, my friend just recommended it to me today. Where do I mark it as answered?

Comment: Alright, all done, could you maybe explain what the three different things does? The last "write-host" is easy enough, but I'd like to know what the rest is about

Comment: comments added to the script